# how the best way to define the specific place that the symbol can occupy?

Tags: android, kotlin, tic-tac-toe

I am to develop a tic tac toe game in android. I have a image with the game board and initially the symbols of the game (three x and three o) is outside the game board.
I think that is good the user can move the symbols of game for the game board. 
I saw the code below for move the symbols.

```
        imageView_x1.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
            override fun onTouch(view: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                when (event.actionMasked) {
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                        xCoOrdinate = view.x - event.rawX
                        yCoOrdinate = view.y - event.rawY
                    }
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> view.animate().x(event.rawX + xCoOrdinate)
                        .y(event.rawY + yCoOrdinate).setDuration(0).start()
                    else -> return false
                }
                return true
            }
        })
```

My question is, how the best way to define the specific place that the symbol can occupy? Saving the exactually the coordenates? 
But and if the user put the symbol in the x coordenate "one step" to the left? The place occupy is right, therefore saving the exactually the coordenates isn't the best way, I guess.

Comment: Create some distance variable and on ACTION_UP, if the piece is within that distance of a valid coordinate, you can allow it to be placed.

Comment: thx, i think this can be a good option.

Comment: Actually, I think I would make the distance criteria half the length of the diagonal of one of the squares. So the effective circles that are checked for each square will overlap slightly. And on ACTION_UP, find the closest point and determine if that is in the distance. This way, you can drop anywhere on the board and it will find the closest square to check.